# Replace the whole word that starts with a pattern using gsub in R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, gsub

I'm having issues with a problem that should be so simple to resolve.
I'd like to replace the whole words in a string which start with a pattern.

```
> test <- "i really wasn aware and i wasnt aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't."

    ## this is what i want
    > output
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't."
```

the best one I've come with so far is this

```
# this is what get, but it's not correct
> gsub("\\<wasn*.\\>", "wasn't", test)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't't aware. Just wasn't't."
```

I'm really running out of ideas. I would also be happy with

```
 # second desired output without the . at the end
    > output
    [1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't"
```

---

Edit: it seems my question was a bit too specific. so, i'm adding other test cases. Basically, i wouldn't know what character(s) would follow "wasn" and i would like to convert all to wasn't

```
> test <- "i really wasn aware and i wasnt aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn45'e meant to be. it wasn@'re simple"
> test
[1] "i really wasn aware and i wasnt aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn45'e meant to be. it wasn@'re simple"

#desired output
> output
 [1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn't meant to be. it wasn't simple"
```

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169450/3832970), the solution is case insensitive (will work for `Wasnmnnt`, too) and deals with all punctuation, not just `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead provided by perl.. `pattern=wasn(?!')t*`

```
gsub("wasn(?!')t*","wasn't",test,perl=T)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't."
```

or you can do:

```
gsub("wasn'*t*","wasn't",test)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't."
```

For the second desired output:

```
gsub("wasn'*t*[.]?","wasn't",test)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't"
```

AFTER THE EDIT:

```
gsub("wasn[^. ]*","wasn't",test)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn't meant to be. it wasn't simple"
```

Comment: That's so much better, thank you. However, i believe my example was a bit specific so edited my question again. the fact is that i wouldn't know what character(s) would follow "wasn" and i still would like to covert all to wasn't. I've edited my question to accomodate for this.

Comment: I see what you mean.. This is simple still. One moment

Comment: The `AFTER THE EDIT` solution may gobble trailing punctuation proper and does not account for the capitalized `Wasnnnnt` cases. See [your solution demo](https://ideone.com/LW4lmW) with additional strings. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169450/3832970) using backreferences, word boundaries and a Unicode category class `\p{P}`.

Comment: in your case, you do not need a lot. Just add the two missing ie `?` and `,` ..Thus the regrex wii be `gsub("(wasn)[^.?, ]*","\\1't",test,T)`

Comment: @Onyambu No, it won't work in case 1) `was` is not at the beginning of the word, 2) if there are `.`, `?`, `,` in-between the special chars, 3) cases when wasnt is capitalized.

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you mean. But Op question did not have that.. Anyway you will just invoke a boundary

Comment: `gsub("\\b(wasn)\\S*?(\\p{P}{1})*(\\s|$)","\\1't\\2\\3",test,T,perl = T)`

Comment: @Onyambu `(\\p{P}{1})*` = `\\p{P}*`. Besides, instead of `(\\s|$)` in a PCRE pattern it is more efficient to use `(?!\\S)`. I agree it was not in the question, but OP mentions the data can be very messy.

Comment: Actually that should be `(\\p{P}{1})?` or `(\\p{P}{0,1})` so should not have `*`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a solution like this:

```
test <- c("i really wasn aware and i wasnt aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn45'e meant to be. it wasn@'re simple", "Wasn&^$tt that nice?", "You say wasnmmmt?", "No, he wasn&#t#@$.", "She wasn%#@t##, I know.")
 gsub("\\b(wasn)\\S*\\b(?:\\S*(\\p{P})\\B)?", "\\1't\\2", test, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't. this wasn't meant to be. it wasn't simple"
[2] "Wasn't that nice?"                                                                                                          
[3] "You say wasn't?"                                                                                                            
[4] "No, he wasn't."                                                                                                             
[5] "She wasn't, I know."
```

See an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/JHlAg5).

This solution accounts for cases when `wasn*` appears at the start of the string or is capitalized, and does not replace the trailing punctuation.

**Pattern details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(wasn)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `\\1` in the replacement pattern): a `wasn` substring (case insenstive due to `ignore.case=TRUE`)
- `\\S*\\b` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace followed with a word boundary
- `(?:\\S*(\\p{P})\\B)?` - an optional non-capturing group, matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
  - `(\\p{P})` - Capturing group 2 (later referred to with `\\2` in the replacement pattern): any 1 punctuation (not a symbol! `\p{P}` is not equal to `[:punct:]`!) symbol not followed with...
  - `\\B` - a letter, digit or `_` (it is a non-word boundary pattern).

For even messier strings (like `She wasn%#@t##,$#^ I know.`), when the punctuation can be inside other punctuation symbols, you may restrict the punctuation you want to stop at using a custom bracket expression and adding a `\S*` at the end:

```
gsub("\\b(wasn)\\S*\\b(?:\\S*([?!.,:;])\\S*)?", "\\1't\\2", test, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXHhWW/3).

Comment: You are looking for `gsub("(wasn)[^.?, ]*","\\1't",test,T)`

Comment: @Onyambu No, it won't work in case 1) `was` is not at the beginning of the word, 2) if there are `.`, `?`, `,` in-between the special chars.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew. Wow, this is very useful. I'll definitely use your solution for more strict rules. for the purpose of my use case, I'm happy with the solution that considers 'wasn' only at the beginning of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple and replace any word that starts with `wasn` with `wasn't`?

```
test2 <- paste0(
  "i really wasn aware and i wasnt aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just",
  "wasn't. this wasn45'e meant to be. it wasn@'re simple"
)
gsub("wasn[^ ]*", "wasn't", test2)
[1] "i really wasn't aware and i wasn't aware at all. but i wasn't aware. just wasn't this wasn't meant to be. it wasn't simple"
```

If dealing with upper-case also then you could just add `ignore.case = TRUE` to gsub().